# Jenkins JCasC configuration LDAP and authorizationStrategy RoleBase

Tags: java, jenkins, ldap

I'm traying to configure a Jenkins witj JCasC option from helm chart bust this does not work properly, this is my configuration:

```
  JCasC:
    defaultConfig: true
    configScripts:
      welcome: |-
       authorizationStrategy:
        roleBased:
          roles:
            global:
              - name: "admin101"
                description: "Jenkins administrators"
                permissions:
                  - "Overall/Administer"
                assignments:
                  - "admin101"
              - name: "readonly"
                description: "Read-only users"
                permissions:
                  - "Overall/Read"
                  - "Job/Read"
                assignments:
                  - "authenticated"
      securityRealm:
        ldap:
          configurations:
            - server: "ldaps://d.test.domain.lan:636"
              rootDN: "DC=test,DC=domain,DC=lan"
              managerDN: "CN=user-jenkins,OU=JENKINS,OU=services,DC=domain,DC=lan"
              managerPasswordSecret: aaaaa-test1234
              userSearch: "sAMAccountName={0}"
              groupSearchFilter: "(&(cn={0})(objectclass=group))"
              groupMembershipStrategy:
                fromGroupSearch:
                  filter: "(&(objectClass=memberof))"
          cache:
            size: 100
            ttl: 10
          userIdStrategy: CaseInsensitive
          groupIdStrategy: CaseSensitive
```

In the same way I'm trying to configure a user by default using a Role-Base plugin but I dont know how I need to pass the configuration to the values helm.

This is the error:

```
024-01-08 14:19:08.283+0000 [id=33] SEVERE  jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1#onTaskFailed: Failed ConfigurationAsCode.init
io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: No configurator for the following root elements authorizationStrategy, securityRealm
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:756)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:797)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:783)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:652)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:314)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:306)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:115)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:185)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
2024-01-08 14:19:08.284+0000 [id=24]    SEVERE  hudson.util.BootFailure#publish: Failed to initialize Jenkins
io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfiguratorException: No configurator for the following root elements authorizationStrategy, securityRealm
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.invokeWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:756)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.checkWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:797)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:783)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configureWith(ConfigurationAsCode.java:652)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.configure(ConfigurationAsCode.java:314)
    at io.jenkins.plugins.casc.ConfigurationAsCode.init(ConfigurationAsCode.java:306)
Caused: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:109)
Caused: java.lang.Error
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder.invoke(TaskMethodFinder.java:115)
    at hudson.init.TaskMethodFinder$TaskImpl.run(TaskMethodFinder.java:185)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.runTask(Reactor.java:305)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins$5.runTask(Jenkins.java:1170)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$2.run(Reactor.java:221)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor$Node.run(Reactor.java:120)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Caused: org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.ReactorException
    at org.jvnet.hudson.reactor.Reactor.execute(Reactor.java:290)
    at jenkins.InitReactorRunner.run(InitReactorRunner.java:49)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.executeReactor(Jenkins.java:1205)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.<init>(Jenkins.java:992)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:86)
    at hudson.model.Hudson.<init>(Hudson.java:82)
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:247)
Caused: hudson.util.HudsonFailedToLoad
    at hudson.WebAppMain$3.run(WebAppMain.java:264)
```

What I doing wrong ?